# Import a file as a dict() in Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file I was playing around with to see if I can import it and convert it to a Python dictionary.

It is the default `pyenv.cfg` file in `venv`. It reads:

```
home = C:\Users\nope\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.6.4
```

I tried using:

```
with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    new_f = f.read().replace('=', ':')
    d = dict(new_f)
```

This tells me I don't have enough arguments for dict(). It expects 2. I'm familiar with using `dict(zip(list_1, list_2))` to create a dictionary. I'm not familiar with opening a file and creating one.

I'm looking for a very simply way to do this. I did some research with `re` and it isn't turning out. Withing the `with` block, I ran `a = f.read().replace(' = ', '\',\'')` which returns:

```
home','C:\Users\nope\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
include-system-site-packages','false
version','3.6.4
```

Now I need to add a `'` at the beginning and end of each line. Then I think I can use `f.readlines()` to create a list I can slice into keys and values. I know how to do this with `vim` or `sed` in Linux, but I'm trying to stay within Python.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: you are throwing *text* at the dict generator `dict`. It does not work like that.. `print` the `new_f` that you are passing and you will see. Being a file or not is not significant here.

Comment: It turns out `new_f` is a string and that doesn't work unless I pass another argument. Further down, I was able to get a list from `readlines()`  but need to add a `'` at the beginning and end of each line. Have any ideas for that or do you have a better idea for what I'm trying to do overall?

Comment: it is a string that looks like a dict. You have to split it into key,value pairs and feed those to the dict constructor.

Comment: Oh that's right `split()` does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you an alternative one-line style solution using dict comprehension:

```
with open('pyenv.cfg') as f:
    d = {k:v for line in f for k,v in [line.strip().split(' = ')]}

print(d)
# {'home': 'C:\\Users\\nope\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3',
#  'include-system-site-packages': 'false',
#  'version': '3.6.4'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at the builtin [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) library which will return a dictionary like object.

Alternatively you can simply split the lines on `=`

```
my_dict = {}
for line in open(file_path).readlines():
    key, val = line.strip().split('=')  # Remove \n and split on =
    my_dict[key.strip()] = val.strip()  # Remove trailing leading spaces use
    # Note that vals will all be strings you may need to convert type for some
```

Comment: In your case, you need a add a dummy section header to satisfy the configparser requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat it as normal data, don't try to convert it to python or you will end-up going down the horrible `eval` road.

```
d = {}
file = 'pyenv.cfg'

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.rstrip().split(' = ')
        d[k] = v

import pprint
pprint.pprint(d)
```

Gives:

```
{'home': 'C:\\Users\\nope\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3',
 'include-system-site-packages': 'false',
 'version': '3.6.4'}
```

Comment: I would suggest not using the keyword `file` as a variable. There also might be problems if the number of spaces round `=` is not exactly 1 each side.

Comment: @SteveBarnes:  `file` is not a keyword (see `keyword.kwlist`).  It used to be an alias for `open` in the old python 2, but we have gone past that a long time ago.  I tend to avoid it myself, but the OP used it.